# Python Wand open a img file as blob, md5 is incorrect. Is this the Wand's bug?

Tags: wand

Python Wand open a img file as blob, md5 is incorrect.

```
with Image(filename=picture) as img:
    blob = img.make_blob()
    print 'blob md5', hashlib.md5(blob).hexdigest()
with open(picture, 'rb') as img:
    content = img.read()
    print 'content md5', hashlib.md5(content).hexdigest()
```

Comment: there 2 ways to open img as binary, the md5 is different. Any body can share?

Answer (score 1):

[`.make_blob()`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.5/wand/image.html#wand.image.Image.make_blob) method does not write the exactly same binary to its source file.  Use [`.signature`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.5/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.signature) property instead if you want the signature of the image *pixels*, not *file representation*.